# trying (and failing) to compare 2 lists with sequences of protein fragments

Tags: python

so i wrote this chunk of script:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import SeqUtils

protein = SeqIO.parse('short_protein.fasta', 'fasta')
id_protein = []
sequence_protein = 0   
weight_protein = 0   

for i in protein:
    sequence_protein = (f'{i.seq}')
    id_protein.append(f'{i.id}')
    weight = SeqUtils.molecular_weight(i.seq, seq_type="protein", circular=True)
    weight_protein += (round(weight, 1))

print(f'{str(id_protein)[2:-2]}  {weight_protein:6n}  {sequence_protein}')

protein_fragments = SeqIO.parse('short_protein_fragments.fasta', 'fasta')
id_fragments = []
sequence_fragments = []   
weight_fragments = []   

for i in protein_fragments:
    sequence_fragments.append(f'{i.seq}')
    id_fragments.append(f'{i.id}')
    weight = SeqUtils.molecular_weight(i.seq, seq_type="protein", circular=True)
    weight_fragments.append(round(weight, 1))
    
for item_a, item_b, item_c in zip(id_fragments, weight_fragments, sequence_fragments):
    print(f'{str(item_a)}  {item_b:6n}  {item_c}')

import itertools
from math import isclose

combinations = []
for i in range(len(weight_fragments)):
    for weight_subset in itertools.combinations(weight_fragments, i): 
        if isclose(sum(weight_subset), weight_protein): 
            combinations.append(weight_subset)
print(combinations)

data_fragments = dict(zip(weight_fragments, sequence_fragments))
print(data_fragments)

weight_combinations = [tuple(data_fragments[i] for i in c) for c in combinations]
print(weight_combinations)

import itertools
used_fragments = []
for el in sequence_fragments:
    if el in sequence_protein:
        used_fragments.append(el)

sequence_combinations = []
for i in range(0, len(used_fragments)+1):
    for seq_subset in itertools.permutations(used_fragments, i):
        if (''.join(seq_subset)) == (sequence_protein):
            sequence_combinations.append(seq_subset)
print(sequence_combinations)

if sorted(weight_combinations) == sorted(sequence_combinations): 
    print(f'The sequence "{sequence_protein}" with molecular weight {weight_protein}\ncan be covered by the fragments {str(weight_combinations)[1:-1]}\nwith molecular weights {str(combinations)[1:-1]}')
else:
    print(f'The computed weight combinations do not cover the protein sequence')
```

for the following protein sequence and fragments:

```
seq_compl  3788.4  IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWVQIQDYAINVMQCL
seq_0000  3125.4  SKEPFKTRIDKKPCDHNTEPYMSGGNY
seq_0001  1963.4  KMITKARPGCMHQMGEY
seq_0002   397.5  AINV
seq_0003   484.5  QIQD
seq_0004  1036.3  YAINVMQCL
seq_0005  2267.6  IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV
seq_0006   475.6  MQCL
seq_0007    1724  HMTPCYELHGLRWV
seq_0008  2000.2  DHTAQPCRSWPMDYPLT
seq_0009   811.9  IEEATHM
seq_0010  1397.7  MVGKMDMLEQYA
seq_0011   681.8  GWPDII
seq_0012   647.7  QIQDY
seq_0013  2174.4  TPCYELHGLRWVQIQDYA
seq_0014    1794  HGLRWVQIQDYAINV
seq_0015  1040.3  KKKNARKW
seq_0016  1455.7  TPCYELHGLRWV
```

which has given me a list

> sequence_combinations:

```
[('IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV', 'QIQD', 'YAINVMQCL'),
 ('IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV', 'QIQDY', 'AINV', 'MQCL'),
 ('IEEATHM', 'TPCYELHGLRWV', 'QIQD', 'YAINVMQCL'),
 ('IEEATHM', 'TPCYELHGLRWV', 'QIQDY', 'AINV', 'MQCL')]
```

and

> weight_combinations:

```
[('QIQD', 'YAINVMQCL', 'IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV'),
 ('AINV', 'IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV', 'MQCL', 'QIQDY'),
 ('QIQD', 'YAINVMQCL', 'IEEATHM', 'TPCYELHGLRWV'),
 ('AINV', 'MQCL', 'IEEATHM', 'QIQDY', 'TPCYELHGLRWV')]
```

which essentially both contain the same sets of fragments but in a different order. One was computed from the possible weightcombinations, and the other computed for the possible sequence permutations which corresponded to a given protein sequence. i tried to sort both lists, in order to compare elements, however both lists seem to sort differently?

> sorted(sequence_combinations)

```
[('IEEATHM', 'TPCYELHGLRWV', 'QIQD', 'YAINVMQCL'),
 ('IEEATHM', 'TPCYELHGLRWV', 'QIQDY', 'AINV', 'MQCL'),
 ('IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV', 'QIQD', 'YAINVMQCL'),
 ('IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV', 'QIQDY', 'AINV', 'MQCL')]
```

> sorted(weight_combinations)

```
[('AINV', 'IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV', 'MQCL', 'QIQDY'),
 ('AINV', 'MQCL', 'IEEATHM', 'QIQDY', 'TPCYELHGLRWV'),
 ('QIQD', 'YAINVMQCL', 'IEEATHM', 'TPCYELHGLRWV'),
 ('QIQD', 'YAINVMQCL', 'IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV')]
```

is there any way to make it so that i can verify wether the fragment combinations in list_a == list_b?

Comment: You should not use Biopython for that. It is certainly great when you have the whole thing in mind, it is terribly annoying otherwise. Maybe just explain (scientifically, I'm a protein guy) what you want to do, provide/link a set of sequences, and I'll see.

Comment: i basically have to write a script that, given the input of a file with fragments and a file with a complete sequence, detects which fragment combination has the same weight as the protein, and then checks whether or not this combination of fragments covers the sequence. my reasoning was that if the lists contained the same sets of fragments, that the fragments chosen based on weight do indeed cover the protein.

Comment: There might indeed be a better way about this, but I'll explain why your method doesn't work. `sorted()` orders the list items in alphabetical order. Since each item is an iterable itself, it decides its alphabetical order based on the first item (and if it's a tie, based on the second, etc). So in one case you're sorting the based on 'IEEATHM' and 'IEEATHMTPCYELHGLRWV' and in the other based on 'AINV', and 'QIQD'. But if you did `sequence_sorted = sorted([sorted(s) for s in sequence_combinations])`, it'd be one way around the problem.